# Remove aliases from SQL query in Python with regex?

Tags: python, sql, regex, looker

I'm trying to extract table names from a SQL query and running into some difficulty using Python SQL parsers such as sqlparse. The issue is with aliases - the parser will confuse the real table name with its alias and solely return the alias.

My goal is not to edit the parser, but instead to clear out aliases from the SQL query beforehand using regular expressions so that the parser can do its work.

I also don't need to rename all alias calls in the query to the original name, since the context of this parse only requires the table names and nothing else.

To make it explicit, given this query (as a string):

```
SELECT * FROM schema.table alias
```

The regex would return:
"SELECT * FROM schema.table" - which would then be sent for further processing to get the table name. If there is no alias, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM schema2.table2
```

Then it would return the string unchanged.

How would I do this? Are there any other python sql parsers that would be able to handle this with aliases?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? It searches for a line containing the string `FROM schema.table alias` removes the alias

```
import re
string = """
SELECT * FROM schema.table alias
SELECT * FROM schema.table
"""
remove_table_alias = r'(FROM \w+\.\w+)(\s\w+)$'
print(re.sub(remove_table_alias, r'\1', string, flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM schema.table 
SELECT * FROM schema.table
```